# Error with if statement when runnin R in jupyter

Tags: r, if-statement, jupyter-notebook, conditional-statements

I am running the following `if` conditin in R without any problem:

```
nrow<-ifelse(S1_input, 1, ifelse(S2_input & nchar(bands)>40, 2, ifelse(S1_S2_input & nchar(bands)>40, 3, ifelse (S2_input & nchar(bands)<40, 4, 5))))
```

Where `S1_input`, `S2_input`, `S1_S2_input` are logical variables (TRUE / FALSE) (only one can be `TRUE`, the rest `FALSE`) and `bands` is just a string variable

I am trying to share my code using a Jupiter Notebook and the same line is giving an error but ONLY when `S1_input` is `FALSE`

> Error in S2_input & nchar(bands) > 40: operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
>
> Traceback:
>
> 1. ifelse(S1_input, 1, ifelse(S2_input & nchar(bands) > 40, 2,
>      ifelse(S1_S2_input &
>       .     nchar(bands) > 40, 3, ifelse(S2_input && nchar(bands) < 40,
>       .     4, 5))))
> 2. ifelse(S2_input & nchar(bands) > 40, 2, ifelse(S1_S2_input &
>       .     nchar(bands) > 40, 3, ifelse(S2_input && nchar(bands) < 40,
>       .     4, 5)))

Comment: This may not be relevant, but I notice you mix and match & and &&, which are mixing vectors and scalars. Is that intentional?

Comment: Good point, it was a typo from a previous test I was doing. I have changed it in the question

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in the future, my issue is that I was using the `readline()` function to get user input. (when running in RStudio they were boolean variables T/F). Users were writting TRUE but this is not seen as boolean by my condition. The solution has been to explicitly write `ifelse(S2_input=="TRUE"`...

Another option, use `as.logical(readlines(""))` to make sure the user input is seen as boolean, numeric (`as.numeric`), etc.

Hope it helps!